# Display Jenkins pipeline stage as failed without failing the whole job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong. I would like to failure a Stage1. Stage2 should be green and that case, and I would like to have whole build Success. What I am doing wrong?

```
pipeline{
    agent none
    stages{
        stage ("Stage1") {    
            steps {
                script{
                    catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                        stage ("stege1") {
                            def seekAndDestroy = build job: 'SeekAndDestroy' // it is going FAILURE
                        } 
                    }
                    stage ("Stege2") {
                        sh "exit 0"
                    }
                }
            }                  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move `Stage2` to the stages directive: `stages { stage ("Stage1") {...} stage ("Stage2") {...}}

Comment: still doesn't work. Not sure what I am doing wrong but carchError should overwrite a buildRestult to Sucess and only failed a particular stage.

Answer (score 0):

`catchError` is something similar to `try/catch` block, so you need to catch error of the code you are executing. For details - see documentation: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure

This works:

```
pipeline{
    agent { label 'jdk11' }
    stages {
        stage ("stage 1") {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh "exit 1"
                }
            }
        }
        stage ("stage 2") {
            steps {
                sh "exit 0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is:
[image: Result]

Comment: Karolina Ochlik thanks, but I still have a problem